# Can I recover a file from /dev/null?

Tags: data-recovery

```
mv ~ /dev/null
```

moves my home directory to a black hole. Can I recover my home directory from `/dev/null`?

Comment: This `mv ~ /dev/null` command won't work."_mv ~ /dev/null
Moves my home directory to a (black hole)_" line is totally wrong.

Comment: Also related (and perhaps the best master question we have for this): [I can read from /dev/null; how to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/435887/i-can-read-from-dev-null-how-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The accepted existing answers are at least partially incorrect. `/dev/null` is a "black hole" but you can't move directories to it. The whole `mv ~ /dev/null` thing appears to be some sort of hoax. It *looks* really dangerous but it shouldn't actually work.

Still, I wouldn't recommend testing it on a home directory with irreplaceable data. Here's a quick test harness with a new user called `test`. We'll ask them to move *their* home into the ether.

```
$ sudo adduser test
$ sudo usermod -aG sudo test

$ sudo su test  # we are now running as test but let's check
$ cd ~; pwd
/home/test

$ sudo mv ~ /dev/null 
mv: cannot overwrite non-directory ‘/dev/null’ with directory ‘/home/test’
```

If something you wanted does end up in `/dev/null`, the recovery procedure is the same as any other data loss (as if you typed `rm`). Ideally stop using that disk as quickly as possible and start using something like TestDisk to recover. Our[data-recovery](/questions/tagged/data-recovery) tag can be really helpful here.

---

Just to clarify that you can `sudo mv file /dev/null` where `file` is a single file but this will not delete the file, it will replace `/dev/null` with that file. This has all sorts of fairly important ramifications because things rely on being able to redirect to `/dev/null`. Anyway, here's a simple proof of this as well as a fix in case you do end up moving a file over the top:

```
$ echo "this is my file" > test
$ cat test
this is my file

$ sudo mv test /dev/null
$ cat /dev/null
this is my file

# Fix this!
$ sudo rm /dev/null
$ sudo mknod -m 0666 /dev/null c 1 3
```

Obviously if you want to rescue your file be quick and `cp /dev/null ~/Desktop/file` (or somesuch) before you replace it with the system definition of /dev/null.

Comment: According to [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117960/mv-a-file-to-dev-null-breaks-dev-null) in some systems, moving a file to /dev/null replaces the device instead of removing it.

Comment: Why do you do the move attempt as root? You just said "We'll ask _them_ to move", not "ask _root_".

Answer (score -1):

In such a case, the **first thing** to do is to stop the system. The hope is that the files are still somewhere on the hard disk; by stopping the system we want to avoid that they are overwritten (if removed, they are marked as free space).

The **second thing** to do is to read [data recovery manual](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery) and follow the instructions therein. Unfortunately, this succeeds as often as not.

The **third** is to check your backups (there are two sorts of people: those who do backups and those who will; hope you are the former kind).

Comment: None of this is true or needed, see Oli's answer.