# Why is moving directories to /dev/null dangerous?

Tags: command-line, filesystem

When trying to move a `test_dir` directory to `/dev/null`, I get the message

```
mv: cannot overwrite non-directory ‘/dev/null’ with directory ‘test_dir/’
```

Then why do people say "Don't run the command `sudo mv ~ /dev/null`, it will move your home directory to a hole?"

[Link](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=+sudo+mv+~+%2Fdev%2Fnull)

But `/home` is also a directory.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Because people assume. I was one of those people [until I tested it](https://askubuntu.com/a/435872/449). It's easy to understand why people assume... It *looks* dangerous...

... but you can't actually move things to `/dev/null` — It's a special file that just absorbs redirects (and sends them into nothingness). If you try to move a directory to it, the filesystem will verbosely explode in your face and if you try to move a file to it, you will probably end up replacing it.

The first link will deal with directories, but  here's a separate test just for overwriting it with a file. As Rmano points out in the comments, this is probably something you shouldn't do without adult supervision. There is risk involved.

```
$ echo "this is my file" > test
$ cat test
this is my file

$ sudo mv test /dev/null
$ cat /dev/null
this is my file

# Fix this!
$ sudo rm /dev/null
$ sudo mknod -m 0666 /dev/null c 1 3
```

Comment: Testing is where reality and theory collide 8-)

Comment: No, moving a file to /dev/null will throw out your null device and replace it with that file, not get rid of the file's contents.

Comment: The answer is a bit ambiguous. Moving a file to `/dev/null` will not result in that data being moved into nothingness. It will result in the data being moved alright, but `/dev/null` will be overwritten, and so you can move it back yet :) Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/435887/i-can-read-from-dev-null-how-to-fix-it/435892#435892

Comment: Yep, because `sudo mv file /dev/null` **will** succeed, and can easily lead to a completely unusable system. See my comments on the question linked in the comment of @MalteSkoruppa. This is another clear example of "prepend `sudo` only if you thrice checked you **know** what you're doing" ;-)

Comment: So Oli, no, moving a file to `/dev/null` will not move it into nothingness. Will replace /dev/null with a regular file named /dev/null, and the next time that a maintenance script will do "< /dev/null" you will have a broken system...

Comment: Oli --- if for example the update daemon runs `dpkg-alternative`(1) (or something in this line) between your "sudo mv test /dev/null" and "sudo mknod" you can have a broken system. Probably needing to reinstall. (1) I say this one because I found an usage of "< /dev/null" in `/etc/alternatives` directory.

Comment: You can do experiment creating your own copy of /dev/null: `sudo mknod -m 0666 /tmp/mynull c 1 3` --- and then play away with it ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure about "probably" needing a reinstall... But I'm tempted to test it B)

Comment: Obviously the probability of such a thing is small. Probably the command I found in 'alternatives/lzcmp' will simply fail. But a lot of things use /dev/null to truncate files --- think what can happen if doing that while upgrading a fundamental library. Or configuration file.

Comment: Try just "egrep '< */dev/null' *" in `/usr/bin/`. All those command will fail in that window.

Comment: This is where the best questions come from. "Dear Ask Ubuntu, I recently moved my homework to /dev/null by mistake and that was sucked into 90% of my system configuration files. I now see Shakespeare essays every time I boot. And my trackpad doesn't work. Halp!"

Comment: :-))))))))))))) ROTFL. This made my day. Thanks!

Comment: @Oli Isn't that emacs alt-meta Shakespeare [mode](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/real_programmers.png)?

Answer (score 19):

`/dev/null` is just a file, it's a "special character" file but it's non the less still bound by the rules that files must follow. That being said you could never run this command:

```
$ mv ~ /dev/null
```

The `mv` command won't allow this since you're moving a directory to a file, that just doesn't make sense contextually and `mv` knows this.

#### Example

```
$ mkdir dir
$ touch afile
$ mv dir afile
mv: cannot overwrite non-directory ‘afile’ with directory ‘dir’
```

You can't copy onto `/dev/null` either, given it's a character file, if you try to copy a regular file onto it.

```
$ cp ~/bzip2_1.0.6-4_amd64.deb /dev/null
$ ls -l |grep null
crw-rw-rw-  1 root root        1,   3 Mar 16 14:25 null
```

About the only thing you can do to this file is copy `mv` over it another file or delete it.

```
$ mv /path/to/afile /dev/null
```

After this command, `/dev/null` is a regular file. The most dangerous effect of this change is that `/dev/null` is supposed to **never** output any data, so a number of shell script will assume that

```
`... < /dev/null`
```

is equivalent to say "nothing". Having this assumption broken can lead to random data (well, the data the last process wrote to `/dev/null')  inserted in system files all around the system --- which could lead to an utterly broken and unrecoverable system.

Answer (score 13):

You can write files or other input streams to `/dev/null` but not directories. If you try moving a directory to `/dev/null` it would report an error since `/dev/null` is not a directory but a file.

However, since you want to experiment with `/dev/null`, you are first suggested to know the consequences to moving a file to overwrite `/dev/null` and how to recover from that situation:

- [I can read from /dev/null; how to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/435887/i-can-read-from-dev-null-how-to-fix-it)

As suggested by [@Rmano](https://askubuntu.com/users/16395/rmano) in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/435891/114818) to that question, in order to experiment with `/dev/null` we should rather create a copy of it and then do our experimentation. So, let's create `/tmp/null` and use it for our experimentation purposes:

```
sudo mknod -m 0666 /tmp/null c 1 3
```

Now onwards, `/tmp/null` is our `/dev/null` for all purposes:

Let us create a `test_file` and a `test_dir` inside a directory called `ask_ubuntu`.

```
$ mkdir ask_ubuntu
$ cd ask_ubuntu
$ touch test_file
$ mkdir test_dir
$ echo "Let us test if we can recover our test_file." > test_file
```

The following shows the contents of `ask_ubuntu` directory:

```
$ ls -la
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 aditya aditya 4096 Mar 18 17:10 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 aditya aditya 4096 Mar 18 17:10 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 aditya aditya 4096 Mar 18 17:10 test_dir
-rw-r--r-- 1 aditya aditya    0 Mar 18 17:10 test_file
```

Now try to move our `test_file` to `/tmp/null` and see the contents of `ask_ubuntu`:

```
$ sudo mv test_file /tmp/null   # This succeeds
$ ls -la
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 aditya aditya 4096 Mar 18 17:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 aditya aditya 4096 Mar 18 17:10 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 aditya aditya 4096 Mar 18 17:10 test_dir
```

The command succeeds and `test_file` is no longer available. Now try to move `test_dir` to `/tmp/null` which doesn't succeed:

```
$ sudo mv test_dir/ /tmp/null 
mv: cannot overwrite non-directory ‘/tmp/null’ with directory ‘test_dir/’
```

`test_dir` is still present inside `ask_ubuntu`:

```
$ ls -la
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 aditya aditya 4096 Mar 18 17:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 aditya aditya 4096 Mar 18 17:10 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 aditya aditya 4096 Mar 18 17:10 test_dir
```

Now, let us figure if we can recover our `test_file` from `/tmp/null`:

```
$ cat /tmp/null
Let us test if we can recover our test_file.
```

So, it is still there and `/tmp/null` which was a special file has been overwritten and it has become like any other normal file. We can recover our file by copying `/tmp/null` just like any other file:

```
$ cp /tmp/null our_test_file
$ cat our_test_file
Let us test if we can recover our test_file.
```

File recovered.

#### Note:

If you didn't create `/tmp/null` and tried those commands directly using `/dev/null`; make sure you recover the file (if you need to) by running `cp /dev/null our_test_file`; and restore `/dev/null` for the purposes it exists on our system by running the following commands as given in the linked question as soon as possible:

```
$ sudo rm /dev/null
$ sudo mknod /dev/null c 1 3
$ sudo chmod 666 /dev/null
```

#### Conclusion:

- So, it is impossible to move a directory to `/dev/null` and hence there is no question of recovering the directory from there.
- As far as files are concerned, if you directly move files to `/dev/null`, you can still recover it as demonstrated above. However, there are two exceptions:

  1. During the period you run `sudo mv test_file /dev/null` and `cp /dev/null our_test_file`, if any root script in the system overwrites it by running `echo "Whatever text the root script wants to send to /dev/null" > /dev/null` (or other similar commands). Then we do not have any easy way to recover our file.
  2. If you reboot the system between running those two commands. `/dev/null` gets re-created at boot, so our file gets lost when we shut down the computer.
- But if you want to recover input streams like `echo "Stream this line to /dev/null" > /dev/null`, you cannot recover that since `/dev/null` is a special file to dispose off unwanted files and input streams and as the Wikipedia article mentions, it doesn't provide any data to a process that reads from it.

---

Reference: [Wikipedia Article on `/dev/null`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/null)

Comment: `sudo mv test_file /dev/null` replaces  `/dev/null` with `test_file`. So after that `/dev/null` is just a normal file and you can read from it anything you wrote into it. ***DON'T DO THAT***

Comment: "So, it's not possible to recover any file that you have moved to /dev/null" strictly speaking not true. If you were to shut down the system, mount it and run data recovery on it, you might very well be able to recover the file if it hadn't been overwritten.

Comment: @FlorianDiesch: Updated the answer :)

Answer (score 7):

Everything sent to `/dev/null` is silently discarded.
If you type:

```
echo "Hello World"
```

you get `Hello World` on the screen.
If you type:

```
echo "Hello World" >/dev/null
```

you don't get anything on the screen.

But in the case of the move command, the command `mv` try to replace the file /dev/null by the directory, what is not possible. Because everything is a file in Linux, /dev/null is a file. A special one of course (a device file), a special file allowing accessing piece of hardware (like disks, partitions, sound cards, serial ports, ...). In the case of /dev/null, this is not linked to any piece of hardware so the data sent to it is silently discarded. This is why "they" may have called it a blackhole.

Comment: directories are not files.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen In Linux world, directories are files!

Comment: @HabeebPerwad only inside the kernel.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Sorry, I didn't get into kernel, so no idea :)

Comment: "Because everything is a file in Linux" - Incorrect. There are files and also a lot of other kinds of objects. Not sure where you got this.