# I can read from /dev/null; how to fix it?

Tags: udev

I read the [Wikipedia article on `/dev/null`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/null) and was playing around by moving files to `/dev/null`.

For this I created a `test_file` and put some contents in it:

```
$ touch test_file
$ echo "This is written by Aditya" > test_file
$ cat test_file
This is written by Aditya
```

Thereafter I tried to move the file to `/dev/null`:

```
$ mv test_file /dev/null
mv: inter-device move failed: ‘test_file’ to ‘/dev/null’; unable to remove target: Permission denied
```

Since, this gave me a `Permission denied` Error; I went ahead and used `sudo` as I normally do whenever I encounter a `Permission denied` error.

```
$ sudo mv test_file /dev/null
```

The command succeeded and `test_file` is no longer present in the directory.

However, the Wikipedia article says that it is not possible to recover anything moved to `/dev/null` and it gives an `EOF` to any process that tries to read from it. But, I can read from `/dev/null`:

```
$ cat /dev/null
This is written by Aditya
```

What did I do wrong and how do I fix `/dev/null` back to normal? And why did I encounter `Permission denied` error in the first place?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

`/dev/null` is a file. A special file. A device file like /dev/sda or /dev/tty that talks to a piece of hardware on your system.

The only difference with `/dev/null` is that no hardware is linked to it. Any data you send to it is silently discarded. Like the following command:

```
echo "Hello World" > /dev/null
```

which won't print anything on your terminal because you send the output of `echo` to null, to the void, a black hole thus.

But when you did `mv test_file /dev/null` you've replaced the special file `/dev/null` by a normal text file, holding a copy of the content of your `test_file`.
In other words, you've lost your `/dev/null`.

Now, what you have to do is (to reconstruct it):

```
sudo rm /dev/null
sudo mknod -m 0666 /dev/null c 1 3
```

You should reconstruct it because a lot of scripts by default send output to `/dev/null`. If `/dev/null` is no more a black hole but a regular text file, it may grow, grow and fill your file-system up. And I'm sure you want to avoid this.

And much more dangerous, a lot of scripts assume that reading from `/dev/null` will read nothing; breaking this assumption can lead to random garbage written in files all around your system... practically impossible to fix up.

And remember that Linux is multi-tasking: while you are playing with `/dev/null`, a lot of processes are running and can wreak havoc even during a few seconds "window of opportunity".

If you want to play with `/dev/null` you can create a copy and experiment with it:

```
sudo mknod -m 0666 /tmp/null c 1 3
```

Will create a `/tmp/null` file that works in the exactly same way of `/dev/null` but that you can manipulate and test without any risk for your system.

Answer (score 18):

There is a big difference between *overwriting* a file and *writing to* a file.

When you *write something to* `/dev/null`, e.g.,

```
$ echo Hello > /dev/null
```

...it gets silently discarded. For this you need write permissions to `/dev/null`, which everyone has:

```
$ ls -l /dev/null 
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 3 Mar 18 13:17 /dev/null
```

When you *overwrite* `/dev/null`, as you did with the `mv` command, you replace the special file `/dev/null` with whatever you moved there. **Don't do this!** The reason you needed root privileges to do that is because to overwrite a file, you need write permissions *to the directory that contains the file*, in this case `/dev`:

```
$ ls -ld /dev
drwxr-xr-x 16 root root 4640 Mar 18 13:17 /dev
```

To restore `/dev/null`, issue the commands

```
$ sudo rm /dev/null
$ sudo mknod -m 0666 /dev/null c 1 3
```

(Also see [U&L StackExchange: How to create `/dev/null`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27279/how-to-create-dev-null))

Answer (score 8):

When you run the command

```
$ sudo mv test_file /dev/null
```

you have *replaced* the special file `/dev/null` with your text file. Subsequent attempts to read from `/dev/null` return the contents of your text file, and programs that attempt to use `/dev/null` in the normal way will probably break.

Replacing or deleting device files in `/dev/` requires superuser privileges, which is why your non-sudo attempt failed with an error.

See Benoit's answer for information on how to restore `/dev/null` manually, but since most (if not all) of the content of `/dev/` is managed dynamically by udev, I suspect a simple reboot will probably fix it too.

Answer (score 6):

To answer your question of what you should have done, to remove a file, you do:

```
rm test_file
```

As others have stated, /dev/null is a destination for the output of programs.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the question is not about removing file... I know we use `rm` to remove files/directories... I just read about `/dev/null` and in order to understand more about it, I tried to move files to `/dev/null` and see the effect.. This question is about understanding what did I do wrong by moving files to `/dev/null` as a result of which I can read from it now... The question is not about how to remove files from system... I hope it is clear... But your answer is still welcome and good enough to be kept as an answer... :-)

Comment: To be fair, asking "What did I do wrong" kind of calls for an explanation of what should have been done instead. It probably is trivial for most users but none of the other answers even mentioned it.