# Wrong permissions of /dev/null (XUbuntu 15.10)

Tags: permissions, xubuntu, lightdm

After running update today and rebooting the OS lightdm would not start. After some debugging I noticed that /dev/null (and some other /dev files) do not have adequate permissions (compared to another Ubuntu box I have) - e.g. 'others' could not read nor write /dev/null.

After 'chmod a+rw /dev/null /dev/urandom /dev/random /dev/ptmx' lightdm started up. Of course this is not reboot persistent so I need to put this in some /etc/rc.* to make it stick - which I do not want to!

Anyone knows why this started to happen? IOW, it worked up till today for me.

[SOLVED] I had custom buggy udev rules that would set certain /dev entries to 0600!

Comment: You are stepping over one important question: why do you need to change it? Ever reboot will recreate /dev/. If /dev/null is wrongly created this is a ***serious*** bug and should be reported as such. Please do so. Recreating `/dev/null` should be done as shown here http://askubuntu.com/a/435891/15811  but this is almost only happening when someone himself messed with it and not through the system itself. That would be very bad.

Comment: My thoughts exactly, I should not need to worry about! I have not touched the /dev files in any way. The /dev/null is a proper device node already, no need to recreate it myself, I think. It is only permissions that are wrong IMO. Where do I report bug?

Answer (score 1):

As Rinzwind properly mentioned, `/dev/null` is [created on every boot](http://www.linux.org/threads/overview-of-dev-null.8113/) , but specifically every device including `/dev/null` is created by MAKEDEV script, which is referenced in several `/etc/init` scripts as shown bellow:

```
xieerqi:$ sudo grep -iR "makedev" /etc 2 > /dev/null                                                                                  
[sudo] password for xieerqi: 

    xieerqi:$ sudo grep -iR "makedev" /etc 2> /dev/null                                                                                   
    [sudo] password for xieerqi: 
    /etc/init/mounted-dev.conf: /sbin/MAKEDEV std fd ppp tun
    /etc/init/mounted-dev.conf:     /sbin/MAKEDEV console
    /etc/init.d/udev:create_dev_makedev() {
    /etc/init.d/udev:  if [ -e /sbin/MAKEDEV ]; then
    /etc/init.d/udev:    ln -sf /sbin/MAKEDEV /dev/MAKEDEV
    /etc/init.d/udev:    ln -sf /bin/true /dev/MAKEDEV
    /etc/init.d/udev:    create_dev_makedev
```

The `/sbin/MAKEDEV` and `/sbin/makedev` are the same script, which have in the header settings for all the devices and their respective permissions. In particular, on makedev  my system creates the null device with `$public` permissions:

```
makedev null c 1 3 $public
```

At the top the public is defined as `public="  root root   0666"`

You should be able to open this script and modify the permissions as necessary or verify they are not altered in any way.

However, if they are unaltered, it is strongly recommended to report this behavior as bug, and for your own convenience probably switch to `gdm` for the time being.

Comment: Looking at the /sbin/MAKEDEV I have exactly the same lines for /dev/null. Who should I report bug to?

Comment: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bugs

Comment: Thanks! /etc/init.d/udev, linked to /etc/rcS.d/S03udev, is the place where a call to create_dev_makedev() should create link /dev/MAKEDEV -->/sbin/MAKEDEV.  There is no /dev/MAKEDEV in my /dev folder. Also looking at the /var/log/boot.log I can not see any lines from /etc/init.d/udev.. Strange..