# After reboot /dev/null wrong permissions causing services not start. Ubuntu server 16.04

Tags: 16.04, boot, server

This server is on Ubuntu 16.04, Linux 4.4.0-142-genericls

Executing `ls -la /dev/null` after system reboot returns:

> srwxr-xr-x 1 root root           0 Feb 18 23:22 null

The correct `/dev/null` permissions are

> crw-rw-rw-  1 root root      1,   3 Feb 18 15:01 null

The "s" means socket type file, the "x" stands for executable.

Sometimes even removing `/dev/null` with `rm /dev/null` does not work. I have to create it elsewhere and move it to /dev/null:

```
mknod -m 0666 /tmp/null c 1 3
mv /tmp/null /dev/null
```

Many services will not start for the wrong `/dev/null`, including apache2 and mysql.

This post about Xubuntu 15.10 is saying udev conf and MAKEDEV are the players but I still haven't found how to fix them.

[Wrong permissions of /dev/null (XUbuntu 15.10)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/704596/wrong-permissions-of-dev-null-xubuntu-15-10)

Comment: The most likely explanation would be that somewhere (such as a service unit definition, a reboot cron job, or an `rc.local` script) you have a process that's erroneously moving or copying a regular file over `/dev/null`

Comment: I can't tell exactly what was causing this. It started to happen after a system crash and KVM reset.  After several package updates the problem disappeared.